# Interpolate Gaussian grids to regular fixed grids using bilinear interpolation?

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere-modelling, weather-forecasting, climate-models

I want to regrid GCM data available on Gaussian grids to regular grids, say at 1 deg X 1 deg.
How to do this using `CDO` or `Python` or `MATLAB`.

**Edit 1:** Data format is `netcdf`.

Comment: For the usage of CDO: Do you have your data available as netCDF files? How is your output grid exactly defined? The easiest way with cdo: create a grid description file of the target grid (with `griddes` from an existing target grid netCDF file) and apply an interpolation routine (e.g. `remapbil`) on your files that should be converted.

Comment: With respect to Matlab: The second and third search result (when I just searched it) provide the [interp2](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html) and [griddedInterpolant](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/grid-based-interpolation.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) functions which seem to be what you need. Please provide more information if you need further help.

Comment: @daniel.neumann thanks for your valuable suggestion, my data is in `netcdf` format. I am not sure whether `interp2` can be applied on `Gussian Grids` though I have used this function heavily for `rectilinear grids`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## climate data operators (CDO)

### define grid

We define a lat-lon target grid with 1°x1° grid cell size 30x30 grid cells starting at 40°N and -10°E (=10°W):

```
gridtype = lonlat 
xsize    =  30 
ysize    =  30 
xfirst   = -10 
xinc     =   1 
yfirst   =  40 
yinc     =   1
```

This text is written into a text file. See [section 1.3.2 CDO Manual](https://code.zmaw.de/projects/cdo/embedded/index.html#x1-150001.3.2) for details and further examples.

If you already have a netCDF file which has data on your target grid, you can also extract the grid definition from that file:

```
cdo griddes FILE_WITH_TARGET_GRID.nc > myGridDef
```

`myGridDef` is a text file.

### interpolate data

I assume that we do a bilinear interpolation. This is done with the `remapbil` operator via:

```
cdo remapbil,myGridDef INPUT_FILE.nc OUTPUT_FILE.nc
```

The grid of your input data needs to be properly defined in your input file (that is often a problem).

### 'properly defined' grid

#### Alternative 1

The spatial dimensions of the data variable (SST in the example below) need to be named `lon` and `lat`. Additionally, coordinate variables `lon` and `lat` have to exist (time independent!). These need to have correct coordinate variable attributes (see example below).

Example:

```
dimensions:
    lon = 30 ;
    lat = 30 ;
    time = UNLIMITED ; // (24 currently)
variables:
    double lon(lon) ;
            lon:standard_name = "longitude" ;
            lon:long_name = "longitude" ;
            lon:units = "degrees_east" ;
            lon:axis = "X" ;
    double lat(lat) ;
            lat:standard_name = "latitude" ;
            lat:long_name = "latitude" ;
            lat:units = "degrees_north" ;
            lat:axis = "Y" ;
    double time(time) ;
            time:standard_name = "time" ;
            time:long_name = "time" ;
            time:units = "seconds since 1900-01-01 00:00:00" ;
            time:calendar = "standard" ;
            time:axis = "T" ;
    float SST(time, lat, lon) ;
            SST:long_name = "sea_surface_temperature" ;
            SST:units = "degree celsius" ;
            SST:_FillValue = NaNf ;
            SST:missing_value = NaNf ;
            SST:var_desc = "sea surface temperature" ;
```

#### Alternative 2

The spatial dimensions and corresponding variables exist in the source file but are not denoted as `lon` and `lat`. Then each data variable (SST, in this example) needs to have an attribute `coordinates` that holds the names of the coordinate variables.

```
SST:coordinates = "lon lat" ;
```

Example:

```
dimensions:
    TSTEP = UNLIMITED ; // (24 currently)
    COL = 112 ;
    ROW = 106 ;
variables:                     " ;
    double lon(ROW, COL) ;
        lon:standard_name = "longitude" ;
        lon:long_name = "longitude coordinate" ;
        lon:units = "degrees_east" ;
        lon:_CoordinateAxisType = "Lon" ;
    double lat(ROW, COL) ;
        lat:standard_name = "latitude" ;
        lat:long_name = "latitude coordinate" ;
        lat:units = "degrees_north" ;
        lat:_CoordinateAxisType = "Lat" ;
    double time(TSTEP) ;
        time:standard_name = "time" ;
        time:long_name = "time" ;
        time:units = "seconds since 1900-01-01 00:00:00" ;
        time:calendar = "standard" ;
    float SST(TSTEP, ROW, COL) ;
        SST:long_name = "sea_surface_temperature" ;
        SST:units = "degree celsius" ;
        SST:coordinates = "lon lat" ;
        SST:var_desc = "sea surface temperature" ;
```

#### Note:

If the coordinate variables are missing, then they can be created via the `setgrid` operator. If we want to add a grid definition to the source file then we need the source file's grid definition in the text file (see 'define grid').

```
cdo setgrid,mySourceGridDef INFILE_NO_COORDS.nc INFILE_WI_COORDS.nc
```

Comment: Is there an equally simple way to proceed when setting coordinates for a projected coordinate system? I didn't understand much from the documentation.

Comment: @Janina You mean when you have some projection, which does not project your model grid on a regular lat-lon grid? Do you mean interpolation or just setting a grid definition? Better you ask a new question (refer to this one) including an example of your data set.

Comment: yes, exactly, something like Lambert Conformal Conic etc. Essentially, I wanted to set the grid definition, so that for example in Panoply it would plot the data in the correct geographic location. And yes, ultimately I'm interested in regridding. Ok, I guess I'll turn this into a question... :-)

Comment: @Janina I just re-read my answer. It actually solves your issue if you already have your coordinates available in one netCDF file.

Comment: You are right, actually. After some trial-and-error progress I was able to do the regridding successfully - thank you for your detailed description! But the validity of my workflow is questionable. I created and saved the data in R with original coordinates in [EPSG:3333](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3333/). I solved the georeferencing problem by adding projection metadata. I did the transformation to WGS84 to get the cell centre coordinates in lat-long and saved them to variables lon and lat (just like your alternative 2). The output of `griddes` for this file was a curvilinear grid.

Answer (score 0):

Using Python, the best solution I've been able to find is pyresample. See this [blog post](http://earthpy.org/interpolation_between_grids_with_pyresample.html).