# snow modelling using raster data with different resolution

Tags: climate, models, water, snow

I am trying model to some snow processes for the whole US. 
I do have daily climate forcing time series for a 1 x 1 km raster in a Lambert Conformal Conic Projection (netCdf format). The MODIS snow cover time series for a grid of 500 m in a sinusoidal projection (hdf format) and snow depth data in a 1 km resolution grid (binary .dat file) in a Geographical projection.

I would like to get the time series for each variable in a 1x1 and 2x2 km grid. 
The question I have is how can this be achieved without using GIS Software. I know how to do this using ArcGIS, but since I do have a lot of files I think there must be a better way of doing this.

My model is in MATLAB, so if there is some toolbox that would achieve that it would be my first choice. However, I am open to other approaches and standalone tools.

Comment: Do you have access to a Linux System or only to Windows? In the first case, the CDOs (climate data operators) do the job as described [here](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/8087/5594).

Comment: I only have access to Windows, but CDO seems to be what I need!

Comment: There is a cygwin (linux shell emulation for Windows) based approach to let CDO run on windows: https://code.zmaw.de/projects/cdo/wiki/Win32

Answer (score 2):

To make sure I'm understanding correctly: You need to reproject some data from one coordinate system to another. Then you need to interpolate or resample it onto a grid.

If you are already familiar with MATLAB, then you can certainly use MATLAB. Look to the Mapping Toolbox for coordinate transforms (although it does not make life easy IMHO), and check out `griddedInterpolant` and `scatteredInterpolant` and their options for interpolation.

If you're more tool-agnostic it might be easier in R (check out the `spatial`, `raster`, and `rgdal` packages). Or, depending on your GIS system, there is probably a way to script or automate it there so that you do not have to work through the process manually for all your files.